# Code runs too slow

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I'm trying to run a code that copies values from one spreadsheet and copies them to another, however the order is not the same(hard to make it an array). In some cases it also prints 'Unknown' and in some it also formats some cells. However it makes way to much time to finish. Is there a way to improve it?

```
function move() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xx');
  var sourceSheet = sss.getSheetByName('CJ_Products');
  var destinationSheet = sss.getSheetByName('Product2');

  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1,1,1).getRow()

  var i = 1

  while(i<=lastRow){
  var rowInt = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, 4,1,1).getRow() //get row number
  destinationSheet.getRange('A' + rowInt).setFormula('=Month(D'+rowInt+')')
  destinationSheet.getRange('B' + rowInt).setFormula('=Weekday(D'+rowInt+')')
  destinationSheet.getRange('C' + rowInt).setFormula('=Day(D'+rowInt+')')
  destinationSheet.getRange('D' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('A'+i).getValues()) //move from the source to destination
  destinationSheet.getRange('E' + rowInt+':F'+rowInt).setValue('Unknown') //set to Unknown
  destinationSheet.getRange('H' + rowInt+':J'+rowInt).setValue('Unknown')
  destinationSheet.getRange('J' + rowInt).setValue('CJ')
  destinationSheet.getRange('K' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('B' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('L' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('E' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('M' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('F' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('N' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('J' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('S' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('G' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('T' + rowInt).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange('H' +i).getValues())
  destinationSheet.getRange('O' + rowInt).setFormula('=S'+rowInt+'*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:EURUSD")')
  destinationSheet.getRange('P' + rowInt).setFormula('=T'+rowInt+'*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:EURUSD")')
  destinationSheet.getRange('Q' + rowInt).setFormula('=P'+rowInt+'/T'+rowInt)
  destinationSheet.getRange('O' + rowInt+':Q'+rowInt).setNumberFormat('0.00$')

  i = i+1
  }
  }
```

Comment: Don't force tags into the question title.

Answer (score 4):

The code should be optimised:

1. You do all calculations in a loop
2. You use `getValue` and `setValue` instead of faster functions `getValues`, `setValues`

Instead of this concentrate your loop to do a single call:

`var rowInt = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, 4,1,1).getRow()`

try to figure out how to find the first row outside the loop and then increment this value:

```
var rowStart = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, 4,1,1).getRow();

for (var row = rowStart; row <= lastRow, row++)
{
  // some code...
}
```

Use arrays and then copy the value from arrays into ranges:

```
var formulas = [];

for (var row = rowStart; row <= lastRow, row++)
{
  // some code...
  formulas.push(['=Month(D'+ row + ')']);
}
var rangeToPateFormulas = destinationSheet.getRange('A' + rowStart + ':A' + lastRow);
rangeToPateFormulas.setFormulas(formulas);
```

And so on. See more info:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices