# Google Script - Insert Column inherits format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've simple code where in A1 there is a date for example **06/06/2017**

What I'm trying it do is to add three columns and set formulas in them.
I add columns by using:

```
ss.insertColumns(1,3);
```

Then I set the formulas in the three columns:

```
ss.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=MONTH(D1);
ss.getRange(1,2).setFormula('=WEEKNUM(D1);
ss.getRange(1,3).setFormula('=CHOOSE( weekday(D1), "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")');
```

However what ends up happening is that all new columns end up inheriting the format of the A columns from before(or at least that's what I think based on my quite limited understanding of Google Script). So in case of new A1 is shows **05/01/1900**. When I click Format>Number>Number it ends up showing **6**. So the number is correct, but the formatting is wrong.

How do I deal with that problem? Bare in mind that the real file has hundreds of rows of dates, I use loops to assign the formulas.

Comment: if **6** isn't what you want, what are you looking for as a result?

Comment: I need it to show 6 without manually clicking Format.

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the number format](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) of a cell at the same time as setting the content or formula. So in the case of

```
ss.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=MONTH(D1);
```

this can become

```
ss.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=MONTH(D1)').setNumberFormat("0")
```

The [possible formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) you can use with `.setNumberFormat(numberFormat)` are the same as you might use within Sheets themselves.

In addition to the solution, a preferable method of the 3 cells being set here (and in association with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512605/google-apps-script-code-runs-too-slow)) rather than set these formulas one at a time, you can set all three with a single call.

```
ss.getRange(1,1,1,3)
.setFormulas([
    '=MONTH(D1)',
    '=WEEKNUM(D1)',
    '=CHOOSE( weekday(D1), "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")'])
.setNumberFormats(["0","0","text"]);
```

Comment: Thank you it works!
I'm very new to Google Script, so all those tips mean a lot to me.

Comment: Just one question - the last line gives some kind of error.

**Cannot convert Array to Object[][].**

Comment: Forgot to wrap it as an array. Downside of writing code from memory on a phone and not testing it.